# jQuery form validation not working in Django

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a simple HTML form in my Django site.

see this http://tinypic.com/r/2ce57rb/6

I want to validate the form on the client side using jQuery but i don't know jQuery or JavaScript.So, i downloaded the form here http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/

and copied all the files to the correct places and the code is the same except some minor modification like name etc. i know they are at correct places because i can see them from the source and i am using twitter bootstrap.

The problem is that no validation occurs after i submit it.

the address bar looks like this after clicking submit 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/?name=&email=&subject=&message=`

Please help i tried many plugins etc. none of them are working!

Comment: @user1042031 http://dpaste.com/hold/768226/ 
This is my template the files in link tag are at there respective places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your bootstrap/docs/assets/js/script.js is incorrect or don't execute ready.
It could be a conflict, do you use dojo, mootools or other ? Try replacing $ involved by the form validation plugin by the jQuery var :

$(document).ready(function() --> jQuery(document).ready(function()

$('#contact-form').validate -->  jQuery('#contact-form').validate

Comment: Thanks for your reply i hadn't placed the call to the jQuery script correctly....once i placed it at the bottom of my file it worked! :)